# Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Shell (Isolated) - Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application

Tags: sql-server, ssms, visual-studio-shell

[Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sqAl.png)

I unstalled all the C++ redistributables, repaired the Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Shell (Isolated) and again installed the redistributables but no success found.

This error message pops up when I try to open Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2018.

I tried in every single possible way. Also reinstalled SQL Server and also the SSMS multiple times. They were installed without any error.

What should I do now?

Comment: Aside... _Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2018_ is not actually a thing. Did you mean _SQL Server Management Studio 18_?

Comment: Are you using Windows 11 22H2? It has been reported to [have issues](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/6b7d06dc-9bec-ec11-a81b-6045bd7ac9f9) due to update KB5014770.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I found out that this problem is related to the Windows insider program.

The following page helped me solve this problem:

https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/6b7d06dc-9bec-ec11-a81b-6045bd7ac9f9

On this page Erin Stellato wrote:

We have a workaround:

Download from https://github.com/thebookisclosed/ViVe/releases

Run (from elevated cmd prompt):

vivetool /disable /name:SV2Navpane

shutdown -r -t0

Answer (score 0):

same issue. switched from Beta Channel to Release Preview Channel

Answer (score 0):

KB5014959 seems to break ssms 18.12.1 and ssms 19. I uninstall it, but it keeps coming back and ssms still does not work. What is going on with Windows 11 and SSMS?

It seemed like it was working before, but the stupid update doesn't let me run SSMS, even if I uninstall it and pause updates, it still comes back, or maybe it doesn't actually uninstall like it says it does.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
[Windows 11 Insider Preview Build 22621.586 and 22622.586](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2022/08/24/announcing-windows-11-insider-preview-build-22621-586-and-22622-586/)

A fix for this issue is now available.